# How to cancel getPage in Htmlunit?

Tags: java, htmlunit

In the htmlunit is there a way to cancel getPage with a Thread other than TimeOut?

I tried Thread.stop but this method is not conveinient.

Answer (score 0):

What I have tried and has worked for me is, right before calling getPage() method (from a WebClient object), create a thread passing in its constructor the same webClient object you'll use to getPage. Then start thread and then call getPage() method. Inside the thread you should call webClient.close() and it will abort getPage method, but you are going to have to handle some exception on getPage() method.

MainThread code:

```
WebClient webClient;

/* Initialize and configure webClient */
/* ... */

YourThread yourThread = new YourThread(webClient);
yourThread.start();

try {
    webClient.getPage(someRequest);
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    /* Ignore, it is caused because of aborting getPage */
}
```

YourThread code:

```
private WebClient webClient;

public YourThread(WebClient webClient) {
    this.webClient = webClient;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    webClient.close();
}
```